# Name of circuits with parallel branches starting and ending at different points

Tags: circuit-analysis

Is there a name for, and where can I find info on, the study of voltage drops, currents and resistances in circuits where 2 parallel branches off a main trunk line might not start and end at the same point?

E.g. below.

Wasn't sure what to search for on google or stack exchange.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyZUb7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There is no special name for *every* possible configuration. There are some topologies that called *star* configuration. Some called *delta*. Google them.

Comment: If you Google "Kirchhoff's Laws exercises" or "Kirchhoff's Laws examples" or ""Kirchhoff's Laws practices" then you'll find a lot of circuit like this one.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I mean cases where the 2 branches not only start/end at different points, but the start&end points of one are not both contained with the bounds of the other. This seems to fundamentally change the rules of how to apply ohm's law, etc., beyond what's described in documents about parallel, series and combination. Kirchoff's Laws seem to study the stuff I'm talking about, thanks Rohat.

Comment: The one you've shown is a  'bridge', but drawn in a confusing way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your circuit, we can redraw it like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxC1Vt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And we can try to use one of a network analysis technics available to us. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_analysis_(electrical_circuits)
For an example: delta-wye transformation, nodal analysis, mesh, Thévenin's theorem etc.

With Thevenin example can be found [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/305507/how-can-i-find-the-equivalent-resistance-in-the-given-circuit/305530#305530)

Answer (score 0):

You're most probably looking for circuits which are usually analysed using Kirchoff's Voltage Law and Mesh Analysis... perhaps you might want to have look at star &  delta connections,  too.

*sigh* Also,  two branches can't be called Parallel branches unless their both ends are common.  If they're are in parallel,  voltage across both of them should be same and this requires for them to between same points (cause we define voltage difference between 2 points as the work required to be done on unit charge for moving it between two points).